# log every method call in JSF using logback

Tags: jsf, logging

Hello guys I'm new in java and JSF, my boss asks me to auto log every events or method call in a web application made with JSF

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for single use case, while I was infront of handling multiple cases especially to reduce source code base on my latest project... and I found shining stuff in form of Aspect Oriented Programming -> AspectJ in Java world.

You can find very nice articles here:
http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html

You can implement the behaviour with custom annotation or simply hard-link it into your application, so you don't need to specify nothing in the code and each event will be autologed with specific behaviour (log with/without data, etc.).

Another very nice example of doing this is here:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-performance-logging

Just to add, same as you log events, you can create AspectJ auto logging in case of error handlers.

Not only this, but you can handle in fully generic way across whole application all errors in unified way by not writing simple line of code in error/event handlers...

**NOTE:** do not reinvent wheel, so look here as other people collected usefull AOP to be reused in your project out of the box :-)) open source is great community:
https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aspects

Comment: keep  in mind that in high performance microservice architectures AOP is sometimes seen as obsolete technology and rather replaced by event middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interceptors for this purpose if your managedbeans are CDI. Check the official tutorial for Interceptor here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv006.htm

Interceptor can intercept every method call in CDI and you can hookup your logging code inside of the interceptor method.

Comment: Thank you very much i will check it out